# Setting up quotas on 64-bit RHEL6 OS with ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, redhat, ext4, quota

Setting up a new 64 bit RHEL 6 server with ext4 FS. Have only worked with ext3 and 32bit RHEL5 before. No matter what I try, I cannot get it to work.

Current settings for mount (from "mount" command):

```
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid)
/dev/sdb1 on /backup type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,noatime)
/dev/sda8 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0)
/dev/sda2 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,noexec,noatime)
/dev/sda6 on /usr type ext4 (rw,noatime)
/dev/sda5 on /var type ext4 (rw,noatime,usrjquota=aquota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

Essentially trying to get user/group quotas on /home, and user quotas on /var. Created the aquota.user and aquota.group files on /home and /var:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 17 13:37 /home/aquota.group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 17 13:37 /home/aquota.user
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Nov 17 11:43 /var/aquota.user
```

When I run quoatcheck I get:

## quotacheck -vguma

```
quotacheck: WARNING -  Quotafile /home/aquota.user was probably truncated. Cannot save quota settings...
quotacheck: WARNING -  Quotafile /home/aquota.group was probably truncated. Cannot save quota settings...
quotacheck: WARNING -  Quotafile /var/aquota.user was probably truncated. Cannot save quota settings...
```

Then I attempt quotaon and get:

## quotaon -av

```
quotaon: Cannot find quota file on /home [/dev/sda8] to turn quotas on/off.
quotaon: Cannot find quota file on /home [/dev/sda8] to turn quotas on/off.
quotaon: Cannot find quota file on /var [/dev/sda5] to turn quotas on/off.
```

quota rpms installed:

## rpm -qa|grep -i quota

```
quota-3.17-16.el6.x86_64
quota-devel-3.17-16.el6.x86_64
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what I should adjust to get quotas to work as they do in ext3/32bit?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Had to first delete the aquota.* files. Seems jquota does not like them existing, even as 0 byte files, like normal quota set ups.